# Why can't I access the current execution context with a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I've been studying closures and callbacks, for the last hours, and I wrote this function to better understand the concepts of closures. I know that in this example, closure is not happening because callback is called inside the same execution context as function one().

```
function one(callback) {
   let a = 1;
   let b = 2;

   callback()
}


one(function () {
   console.log(a);
});
// Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Even though the callback is executed in the same execution context as `function one()`, why can't I access `a` with the callback? 
Is it because let being scope limited and therefore the `callback` cant access it once it reaches to it's execution? Shouldn't the `callback` go down the scope chain and find `a`?

Thank you

Comment: Javascript has *lexical* scope. If a variable is declared in a block, it will be accessible from within that block, and within any descendant blocks, and nowhere else. Here, `a` is not in an ancestor block of the `one` call, so it's not accessible from there.

Comment: So we could say that callback() and a are at the same child level, therefore when I run the callback() it goes down in the chain scope doesn't find a and returns the error?